# How to change a label tag to input text by click a link?

Tags: jquery, html

I have some radioButton with a label tag followed by a a tag. I need when i click the a tag, the appropriate label change into a text field by jquery so i can edit its text?

```
<label for="1_2">Man</label>
<input value="2" disabled="disabled" type="radio" name="1_1" id="1_1" />
<a id="buttonid" name="buttonid" href="#">edit</a><br />
<label for="1_2">Man</label>
<input value="2" disabled="disabled" type="radio" name="1_1" id="1_1" />
<a id="buttonid" name="buttonid" href="#">edit</a><br />
....
```

change into

```
<input value="Man" name="1_2" id="1_2">Man</label>
<input value="2" disabled="disabled" type="radio" name="1_1" id="1_1" />
<a id="buttonid" name="buttonid" hidden="true" href="#">edit</a>
....
```

Comment: Show us some code you've already tried

Comment: I have added some more code. Ok?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps..

**Script**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#buttonid').click(function(){
        $('label').each(function(){
            var text_classname = $(this).attr('for');
            var value = $(this).text();
            var new_html = ('<input value="' + value + '" name="' + text_classname + '" id="' + text_classname + '">' + value + '</label>' )
            $(this).replaceWith(new_html);
        });
$(this).attr('hidden','true');
    })

})

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is near my exact answer but i have to check it more!

Answer (score 1):

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsbin.com/ajUYexI/1/edit)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    var tar_id = $(this).attr("data-label");
    var tar = $("label[for='"+tar_id+"']");
    var val = tar.text();
    tar.replaceWith("<input type='text' name='"+tar_id+"' id='"+tar_id+"' value='"+val+"' />");
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="buttonid" name="buttonid" data-label="1_2" href="#">edit</a>
```

Add one more attribute `data-label="1_2"`

**Similar Code** [<kbd>**9lessons**</kbd>](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/12/flickr-like-title-edit-with-jquery-and.html)

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is too right, but @sSaroj has more complete answer, in special at the end of his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the elements, no problem.

But the more reasonable approach would be to have the input fields ready (but initially hidden), so that when the click happens the label element gets hidden, and the input replacement shows up. This way you'd have a much nicer code, the formatting would be much much easier and consistent and you'll also have less post-submit work to do.

Btw. `<input value="Man" name="1_2" id="1_2">Man</label>` makes no sense and is invalid.